# Activating Input Fields on Contact Form Requires 2 Clicks on Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sorry I don't know exactly how to phrase this issue.

I've made a type of Uber Menu that opens a container with various elements inside it. On PC it works fine, but when you access it via iPhone, I have to first click the input field / links, and then click again in order to activate them..

To see what I mean, click i.e. on the "Contact" button, and try accessing the input fields on the Contact formula. http://www.strengthandfreedom.com/

What is this issue called, and what can I do to make it react on first click on mobile?

Thank you! :-)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1g0Lraec/6/ - this is the code used to hide / show the menu containers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the behavior is occurring, but it may have something to do with the way you're setting/hiding the values to display text onfocus and onblur...

Try swapping it out and using the `placeholder` attribute.

Instead of

```
<input type="text" class="required" name="qcfname1" value="Your Name" onfocus="qcfclear(this, 'Your Name')" onblur="qcfrecall(this, 'Your Name')">
```

try

```
<input type="text" class="required" name="qcfname1" placeholder="Your Name">
```

Comment: Thank you but I can't really use your HTML... the contact form in my menu container is added via a shortcode [qcf] into a custom code block in WordPress.  It's like there's this "layer" over the elements contained in the div that requires you to first click on that, and then you are allowed to access the form. It's weird :-s